# Prior term in SGHMC implementation

Tags: bayesian-network, variational-bayes, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I am working with SGHMC (Stochastic Gradient Hamiltonian Monte Carlo) models.
I found an implimentation of the algorithm in pytorch [here](https://github.com/ruqizhang/csgmcmc). The part of the code that represents momentum variable update (not a complete update):

```
def update_params(lr,epoch):
    for p in net.parameters():
        if not hasattr(p,'buf'):
            p.buf = torch.zeros(p.size()).cuda(device_id)
        d_p = p.grad.data
        d_p.add_(weight_decay, p.data) 
        ...
```

**d_p** here are the gradients of the loss wrt to NN weights and **p** are the actual parameters. I understand that potential energy is a sum of the log likelihood and log prior. To get the gradient of the potential energy we need to take gradient of this sum. Gradient of the loss (CrossEntopy in my case) is basically the gradient of log likelihood, but I don't see where is that second term that comes from the gradient of log prior.

We do *add_(weight_decay, p.data)*, but this term to me seems like an ad-hoc weight decay term (if there was no weight decay this term would be zero). But regardless of the weight decay there should be a term proportional to **p** that represents log prior (in case of the isotropic Gaussian prior). Could you please tell me where I am mistaken?

Thank you.